# restart a service in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

When I try to execute the below code, I get the error - RPC server is unavailable.

```
        string username = "****";
        string password = "****";            
        server = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
        service = "****";
        ServiceController windowsservice = new ServiceController(service, server);
        try
        {                
            ConnectionOptions connectopt = new ConnectionOptions();
            connectopt.Username = username;
            connectopt.Password = password;
            connectopt.EnablePrivileges = true;
            connectopt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\'"+server+"'\\root\\cimv2", connectopt);
            scope.Connect();
        }
```

But when I hardcode the value of server name in the line

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\'"+server+"'\\root\\cimv2", connectopt);
```

it works fine with no errors

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: So why not just use the `ManagementScope` strategy?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.  Both of your code examples look identical.  Look carefully at the string you're passing into your `ManagementScope`; make sure that it is formatted correctly.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You say that one piece of code doesn't work, then post a fragment of the first piece of code (the fragment is identical by the way) and say that *that* works. I have two questions: 1) Why not use what works instead of what doesn't work? and 2) Did you intend to post the ManagementScope line from the first example in the second example, or was that supposed to be something else? Please clarify what your question is here.

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to add the single quotes in that string? It seems your final string will be `\\'someserver'\root\cimv2`

Comment: It did not work. I did not get the value of string when I tried using single quotes

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen When the first set of codes are executed, I'm getting the error. But when I hardcode the value of server in management scope line, it runs fine

Comment: Not enough detail in the question to answer. However, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20service%20%22RPC%20server%20is%20unavailable%22

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen when I hardcode the value of server in management scope line, it just works fine. But when I try to get the value of string using quotes, I'm getting the error

Comment: You didn't show an example of how you hardcoded the server name, you showed a copy of the way you embedded the server name variable into the string from the first example. Can you show your actual code that works? If you have to obfuscate the server name, do that but don't change anything else.